# Dual boot does not load Windows after installing Windows drivers

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows, windows-8

I have a dual-boot machine with Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 14.04. Then, I installed some drivers on Windows from a CD (chipset, NVidia, LAN and audio).

However, when I now boot into Grub and choose Windows, instead of loading up Windows as before the updates, it just sends me to a blank purple screen (the purple that is the Ubuntu colour by default). I have also tried running Ubuntu's boot repair, to no effect.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can boot up Ubuntu?

   try to run

   > sudo update-grub

   and check it its added windows boot
2. Are you using UEFI-Boot?

   --> you should have some UEFI-Boot-Menu where there should be a
   *Windows Boot Manager* entry. Try to hit some keys during boot (F2,
   F10, F12 ...) to get this menu.